# Statistical analysis of an mbox mail file

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a rather large mbox mail file in Thunderbird, around 46.5GB. I want to do some analysis of it to see where the space is used up and what I might do to archive some mail separately.

I tried mboxgrep but it crashed with a segfault on such a large file. Thunderbird can operate on the file, but is extremely slow. The most I can do with Thunderbird is filter the file and then copy all the messages to another folder to see how big the folder becomes. Also the "save as" feature crashes Thunderbird with a large number of mails selected.

I have access to Windows and Linux.

What tools can I use to analyse this file? Specifically, how can I find groups of messages that are somehow related (e.g. they are all from the same source) and see the size of each group?

Comment: My recommendation is to google "mboxsplitter". Saves you some headache. Then use grep on *nix or PowerGrep on Windows.

Comment: @Gantendo thanks, but can you elaborate on how I might use that tool to do the analysis I asked about?

Comment: The mboxsplitter is just to split up a big file into many small ones. Grep or PowerGrep is a tool used to search through text. For example, with powergrep If you search for an email address you can move all mails containing From: thatemail@address.com to a specific folder. Which operating system are you on? Windows?

Comment: @Gantendo The question states what OS I am using. Note that I'm looking for a way to do statistical analysis, not just to grep mails. Thanks.

Comment: I eventually wrote my own software to do this, but can't share it because linking would be doxing myself and I've had problems with trolling on this site. What I can say is that the largest single emails are things like eBay and NASA mails full of Javascript (!), and the largest collections are forum software notifications.